# Can't figure out this java.nullpointerexception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

after thirty minutes of research and staring at this code, I still cannot figure out why a java.nullpointerexception error occurs. This is the main program that creates an array of LongDate (A class that I made) objects. If the error might be in the other classes, ask for the code and I can give it to you. Thanks.

```
public class Assignment1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //creates an array of type LongDate filled with two LongDate objects

    LongDate [] collectionOfDates = { new LongDate("February",2,1996), new LongDate("November",13,1999) };

    // loops through the array and displays output of getDate() for each object

    for( int i = 0; i < collectionOfDates.length; i++ ) {

        System.out.println( collectionOfDates[i].getDate() );

    }

}

}
```

Also, here is the code for LongDate.

```
public class LongDate extends Date {

private String monthName;
private int month;

public LongDate() {

}

public LongDate(String m, int d, int y) {       

    if (monthName.equals("January")) {
        month = 1;
    } else if (monthName.equals("February")) {
        month = 2;
    } else if (monthName.equals("March")) {
        month = 3;
    } else if (monthName.equals("April")) {
        month = 4;
    } else if (monthName.equals("May")) {
        month = 5;
    } else if (monthName.equals("June")) {
        month = 6;
    } else if (monthName.equals("July")) {
        month = 7;
    } else if (monthName.equals("August")) {
        month = 8;
    } else if (monthName.equals("September")) {
        month = 9;
    } else if (monthName.equals("October")) {
        month = 10;
    } else if (monthName.equals("November")) {
        month = 11;
    } else if (monthName.equals("December")) {
        month = 12;
    } else
        month = 0;

    super.setDate(month,d,y);

    monthName = editMonth(monthName);
    super.editDay(d);
    super.editYear(y);

}

public void setDate(String m, int d, int y) {

    if (monthName.equals("January")) {
        month = 1;
    } else if (monthName.equals("February")) {
        month = 2;
    } else if (monthName.equals("March")) {
        month = 3;
    } else if (monthName.equals("April")) {
        month = 4;
    } else if (monthName.equals("May")) {
        month = 5;
    } else if (monthName.equals("June")) {
        month = 6;
    } else if (monthName.equals("July")) {
        month = 7;
    } else if (monthName.equals("August")) {
        month = 8;
    } else if (monthName.equals("September")) {
        month = 9;
    } else if (monthName.equals("October")) {
        month = 10;
    } else if (monthName.equals("November")) {
        month = 11;
    } else if (monthName.equals("December")) {
        month = 12;
    } else
        month = 0;

    super.setDate(month,d,y);

    monthName = editMonth(monthName);
    super.editDay(d);
    super.editYear(y);

}


public String getDate() {

    StringBuilder fullDate = new StringBuilder();
    fullDate.append(monthName);
    fullDate.append(" ");
    fullDate.append(getDay());
    fullDate.append(", ");
    fullDate.append(getYear());

    return fullDate.toString();
}

public String getShortDate() {

    StringBuilder shortDate = new StringBuilder();
    shortDate.append(month);
    shortDate.append("/");
    shortDate.append(getDay());
    shortDate.append("/");
    shortDate.append(getYear());

    return shortDate.toString();
}

protected String editMonth(String m) {

    if (month == 0) {
        m = Input.getString( "Invalid month. Please type the month again." );   
        return m;
    } else {
        return m;
    }

}
}
```

FYI, Date is a class that I was given as a .class file from my teacher. Thus, I cannot give the source code. I do know that it contains (- means private, # means protected, and + means public):

```
-month: int
-day: int
-year: int

#editMonth(int m): int
#editDay (int d): int
#editYear (int y) : int
+Date()
+setDate(int m, int d, int y): void
+Date( int m, int d, int y)
+getDate(): String
+getMonth(): int
+getDay(): int
+getYear(): int
```

Comment: The error is likely in the LongDate class. What line throws the exception? I'm guessing that it's `System.out.println( collectionOfDates[i].getDate() );`, and that you're not setting your Date as you think that you are.

Comment: The LongDate array line. Would you like the LongDate class code?

Comment: Which "LongDate array line"? Where you create the array or where you try to use it? Please be specific. And yes, you will need to show LongDate code.

Comment: If it says line 7 would that be the array line or the system.out line?

Comment: You have your code that you're running in front of you. Check the line numbers. It might not agree with the code you've posted, so better for you to check. You should do this anyway for any and all exceptions. For instance, if you left out the package line, our numbers won't agree. Regardless, check the line number yourself and get back to us.

Comment: It is your LongDate constructor. Show us the code.

Comment: I am writing these files on notepad, and so it doesn't have line numbers. This is the full error though.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at LongDate.<init>(LongDate.java:12)
 at Assignment1.main(Assignment1.java:7)

Comment: Get yourself a better editor, like notepad++, that will show line numbers. In the code, as shown, `monthName` is guaranteed to be `null` in the `LongDate` constructor. It will throw a NPE on the line `if (monthName.equals("January"))`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels nails it again. It's in the constructor. Man, you have psychic abilities.

Comment: Thanks everyone! My program works perfectly now! Woohoo!

Answer (score 3):

As previous posters said, the error is in your `LongDate` constructor. The problem is in the `if` expression. The variable `monthName` has not be initialized. Instead, it should be `m` as that is the parameter.

```
if (monthName.equals("January")) {
    month = 1;
} else if (monthName.equals("February")) {
```

Also, you have similar problems through the class.

Comment: Not only that but the constructor variable name is "m", not monthName. This will never work.

Comment: @mttdbrd Are you saying that if I change all of the monthName's to m and change monthName = editMonth(monthName) to monthName = editMonth(m) it will not fix my program?

Comment: As a side note, that is one of the reasons your TAs, instructors, or professors have office hours and an email address. So that you can approach them.